# SQL query to remove leading zeros for upto 2 entries

Tags: sql

SQL query to remove leading zeros for upto 2 entries. My string is 001145 then return 1145 and if string is 0A1145 then return A1145

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Please post you what you've tried, i.e, your query

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can trim the leading zeros using:

```
select trim(leading '0' from str)
```

Here is one method in SQL Server:

```
select replace(ltrim(replace(str, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

(assuming your string has no spaces in it)

Comment: `trim(leading '0' from str)` is also ANSI SQL compliant!

Comment: @jarlh . . . Very true.  The question was originally tagged with mysql and sql-server, which I why the answer only mentions those databases.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach for SQL Server which'll work if you do have spaces:

```
SELECT STUFF(Col,1,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0]%',Col),0)-1,'')
FROM (VALUES('001145'),('0A12345'),('7895334'),('0123 456A'))V(Col);
```